# ORA-39112 dependent object impdp tips, How do I fix the ORA-39112 error?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle19c

ORA-39112: Dependent object type CONSTRAINT:"xxx7" skipped, base object type TABLE:"xxxx" creation failed
ORA-39112: Dependent object type CONSTRAINT:"xxx7" skipped, base object type TABLE:"xxxx" creation failed

***I am getting the following ORA-39112 error when running an import?
How do I fix the ORA-39112 error?***

Comment: Find the error that prevented the associated table from being created. You can't create a constraint on a base table that doesn't exist.